# How to make header and footer in excel via matlab using excel VBA

Tags: matlab, vba, excel

Im trying to make header and footer in excel via matlab using excel VBA. So far i did some manipulations with cells but header and footer is a problem. 
Here is a code in matlab that opens actxserver and i tried this:

```
Excel = actxserver('Excel.Application');
Workbooks = Excel.Workbooks;
Excel.Visible = 0; 
location=strcat(pwd,'\','testdoc.xlsx');
Workbook = Excel.Workbooks.Open(location);
%%
Excel.PageSetup.LeftHeader='TEST';
%%
Workbook.Save;
Excel.Quit;
```

I am trying to do next. I am trying to make header on the left,center and right side and make a footer with page number on center and two strings on right and left. Lets use this string 'TEST' for all operations in header and footer. I want to do this in matlab of course.

This is the reference https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb225426(v=office.12).aspx

And this is an example how it works in VBA but i dont know how to do that in matlab using actxserver.

```
Sub Date_Time()
    ActiveSheet.PageSetup.CenterHeader = "&D  &B&ITime:&I&B&T"
End Sub
```

Or:

```
Worksheets("SomeSheet").PageSetup.LeftHeader = "Some Text"
```

I am a bit confused. Tnx in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set headers and footers for an individual worksheet, not for Excel itself. So if `Excel` is your MATLAB variable representing a connection to Excel, you could within MATLAB use something like:

```
Excel.Worksheets.Item(1).PageSetup.CenterHeader = 'hello';
```

You can of course refer to `Item(2)` etc for later worksheets, and you can also use the `ActiveSheet` property of `Excel` rather than `Worksheets.Item(1)` to refer to the active worksheet (i.e. `Excel.ActiveSheet.PageSetup.CenterHeader = ...`.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you, it is working! And thank you for the explanation.